# Update bound DataGridView from a worker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, datagridview

maybe my questions sounds stupid, but I'm really stuck on this. Maybe I cannot see the wood for the trees and there's a damn simple solution, but I just don't see it.

I have a bound DataGridView in my C# application (Windows Forms) with the data lying in a database. In regular time intervals my application checks the database tables if there had been any changes (the data changes by external events) and if there are any changes, the DataGridView should be updated.

I hoped it might work this way
- check the database using a worker thread
- if there are changes, change the underlying DataSet object (i. e. reload it from the database, clean it and fill it again) - this should also be done in the worker thread
- invalidate the DataGridView
- on next paint event handler invocation, the DataGridView is updated with the updated contents

What I found out
- I cannot reload the DataSet from the worker thread
- When doing the updates in the UI thread, I have significant performance issues

Is it true that the DataSet (better: the TableAdapters) cannot be manipulated in another thread than the UI thread? Why that?
The DataSet is not directly an UI element and thus COULD allow manipulation from another thread, I guess.
How could (or: should) I solve my issues?
Is there a "best practices" solution?

I mean, Microsoft should be aware of this kind of applications, I guess there are many out there. 
What am I missing?
What's what I didn't understand?

Best,
Thomas

Comment: Some of the functionality you are trying to describe exists natively in a DataAdapter and DataTable; some other functionality may already exist in your DB all without background workers.  Some degree of background work might still be desired, but on the whole this is a bit vague.

Comment: On progress or completed you can change your grid with no issues